# Woocommerce Variable Stock

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I feel dumb asking this but I can't find a clear answer anywhere. If I define stock at the Inventory level it says "this value will be used to control stock for all variations". Does that mean if I put 10 for the stock that each variation has a stock quantity of 10 or does it mean there is a total of 10 for the product that can be sold across all variations?

Comment: As Roeland says below, it is the latter. if you have 10 widgets. If you manage stock at the parent level then all your red, blue, and yellow widgets total up to 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the overall inventory option, the defined amount is for all variations together. When you go into the variations section (of that product), and collapse a variation, you can define inventory on a variation level.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed that was the case but I wasn't 100% sure